# user authentication jsf

Tags: security, jsf, authentication

I want to create user authentication (login) and security page in jsf, that manages user access in my program.
I need a sample or tutorial about that - can you suggest or provide one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Spring, you could take a look at Spring Security. It is a very flexible framework for user authentication:

http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/

Comment: thank's a lot. but i am using jsf. is there for jsf?    i am sory for my question, because i am beginner in framework..

Comment: Many developers are using JSF in combination with Spring. Thats why I mentioned Spring Security. But if you are not using Spring, you should rather go with another solution like jiai suggested!

Answer (score 1):

For glassfish: https://blogs.oracle.com/foo/entry/mort_learns_jdbc_realm_authentication.
If you want to use form based authentication, read the security part of the jee6 tutorial.

Comment: thank you for your help. but your tutorial is quite difficult for me, is there another tutorial based JSF framework?